# First page blank in report

Tags: report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a report in ax 2009 which I want to create a new page for each vendor number.

I have used an `executesSction` - `element.newpage()` on the relevant section which works but always shows a blank page as the first page.

How do I get rid of the blank page?

Comment: If you find an answer useful then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404606/4509) applies to you as well.

You should not call `newpage` the first time. Use a control variable, declare it in `ClassDeclation` of the report.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call newpage AFTER everything is executed for the page.

For example:

```
while (some condition)
{
    this.execute(1);
    this.execute(2);

    if(!lastpage)
        this.newpage();
}
```

Hope that helps!